# Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Running multiple emulators with the same AVD is an experimental feature

Tags: android, android-emulator

I removed the emulator and reinstalled it and got the same error.

> Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Running multiple emulators with the same AVD is an experimental feature.
> Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1.

Comment: hey buddy are you getting your answer ? my emulatro aslo show the same error

Comment: No. I've installed new beta version.  Vipul Chauhan

Comment: Can you please consider accepting one of the answers? Its a good practice to accept useful answer.

Answer (score 160):

Removing the .lock files did the trick for me. Find the avd and remove the lock files. In a Mac `.android/avd/'NAMEOFAVD.avd directory` . The files I removed were  `hardware-qemu.ini.lock` and  `multiinstance.lock`.

Comment: same thing on linux

Comment: rm ~/.android/avd/Pixel_2_API_24.avd/*.lock

Comment: same directory on Windows. I couldn't delete the files. Access denied nonsense. I had to reboot first.

Comment: That worked for me. Just in case I closed the Android Studio, deleted the files, then restarted AS. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04. After that it worked as expected. Just in case, though, I actually had two AVD but I deleted one before closing AS and deleting the locks.

Comment: This occurred after a crash and removing the lock files worked.  Thx.

Comment: I had to open the AVD manager in Android Studio and press on show on disk to get there on mac, but worked out great

Comment: ```rm ~/.android/avd/*.avd/*.lock```

Comment: Thank you! This works even in 2021 on Arch Linux.

Comment: Very thank you, this helped!!

Answer (score 20):

This means that your AVD manager **thinks** that your emulator is running. It thinks that because it sees lockfiles in your avd directory. If your emulator is not running they you can (should) safely delete the lockfiles here :

```
$ rm $HOME/.android/avd/<name-of-your-avd>.avd/*.lock
```

Answer (score 18):

It can be solved using this method. It worked for me.
Follow the steps:

1. Open Android Studio.
2. Go to AVD Manager.
3. In the Actions column, for the respective avd, click on the down arrow and click on Stop.

This will stop the Emulator and then you can restart it from the command line.

Comment: On Android Studio, the AVD Manager should be `Tools -> AVD Manager`. However, this option sometimes disappears. If you can't find it, type `shift` `shift` than type `AVD Manager` to open it.

Answer (score 13):

**On Linux, you should try this:**

```
sudo rm /home/${USER}/.android/avd/*/*.lock
```

**On Mac:**

```
rm $HOME/.android/avd/*.avd/*.lock
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Works for me on Mac

Answer (score 4):

Same emulator error

> `ERROR: Running multiple emulators with the same AVD is an experimental feature.`

fixed with removed lock for AOSP device which located

```
./out/target/product/generic_car_x86_64/multiinstance.lock
./out/target/product/generic_car_x86_64/hardware-qemu.ini.lock
```

Also check permission for /dev/kvm

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you don't have any physical device connected to your computer, in addition to removing all emulators' .lock

Answer (score 0):

The very simple solution which is working all the time is to stop the emulator before launching the new project. If this error comes back you make a duplication of the AVD and delete the old one and run the new one. It works all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the cache could help

```
sudo rm /home/${USER}/.android/avd/*/*.cache
```

Answer (score 0):

just open your task manger, look for `adb.exe`, end task of all `abd.exe` extensions and restart your emulator.

Answer (score 0):

my problem solved by closing the emulator and letting the test run the emulator automatically

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem doing this

Run **cmd as administrator** then

```
RD \S C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Temp
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue, I tried all the solutions above not fixed,
then I used the wipe data option from the device manager then it works fine.