# emulator: ERROR: Running multiple emulators with the same AVD is an experimental feature.Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature

Tags: flutter, android-emulator

I am trying to start the Android Emulator in Android studio for Flutter project.

But I get the following message -

> emulator: ERROR: Running multiple emulators with the same AVD is an experimental >feature. Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature.

I tried the same through Visual Studio Code but faced same problem.

Comment: Did you try using the `-read-only` flag?  Sounds like your options are that, and running just one emulator at once.

Comment: how i can use it ?

Comment: You solved the problem ....
I created a new project now that works everything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Running multiple emulators with the same AVD is an experimental feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328499/emulator-emulator-error-running-multiple-emulators-with-the-same-avd-is-an-ex)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the emulator is still locked.
Remove all the lock file with:
`rm ~/.android/avd/*.avd/*.lock`

Answer (score 1):

**If the emulator is not already running should delete all .lock files**

Find the avd and remove the lock files.

**On Mac:**

```
$ rm $HOME/.android/avd/<name-of-your-avd>.avd/*.lock
```

**On Linux:**

```
sudo rm /home/${USER}/.android/avd/*/*.lock
```

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to encounter this behavior, but it seems that the issue has been resolved by creating a new project. For other folks that still have this issue, there's an open GitHub Issue ticket where you can track its progress: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48894

Answer (score 0):

just to put it out there. Deleting the lock file worked for me as well, but mine was located in a different location as I am not using android studio (developing AOSP by following the guild on https://source.android.com/docs/setup/start#make_a_change )

for me the lock file is located at:

```
~/aosp/pixel3a/out/target/product/sargo/
```

so cd there and:

```
rm *.lock
```

Should fix that.