# flutter mobile(android emulator) http post doesn't reaches website

Tags: android, flutter, http, mobile, request

My http.post request doesn't gives any answer on my mobile(android emulator) flutter.
On the browser it gives the classic XMLHttpRequest error but thats not the topic.

```
final response = await http.post('https://www.notthewebsite.de/420/lalala.php', body: {
  "eMail": eMail.text,
  "password": password.text,
});

var datauser = json.decode(response.body);
```

And it doesn't reaches the website because if it would call website it would insert something into a data base.
But the insertion into the database works when i start the website manually.

Thx for any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me(the first answer, tiny hint for mac i hat to press show on disk in the AVD manager in android studio to get to the folder, else i couldn't find it):
[Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Running multiple emulators with the same AVD is an experimental feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328499/emulator-emulator-error-running-multiple-emulators-with-the-same-avd-is-an-ex/55425191)

Answer (score 1):

Can you access websites on a browser (e.g. Chrome) on the emulator?

I've always needed to start my emulator with the -dns switch, otherwise name resolution fails:

```
c:\AndroidSDK\emulator\emulator.exe -avd Android-28-Playstore-x64 -dns-server 8.8.8.8
```