# "Cannot run program "C:\Users AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe":?

Tags: android, flutter

it's open but not work!

[image: img]

Cannot run program

```
"C:\Users\Farouk\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe": CreateProcess error=1450, Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service

2:28 PM Error Opening Emulator
                ERROR   | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD 
                ERROR   | is an experimental feature.
                ERROR   | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature.
                INFO    | Android emulator version 31.1.4.0 (build_id 7920983) (CL:N/A)
```

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328499/emulator-emulator-error-running-multiple-emulators-with-the-same-avd-is-an-ex#:~:text=The%20very%20simple%20solution%20which,It%20works%20all%20the%20time.