# FlutterAndroid SDK issues on Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sdk, android-virtual-device

I created simple Flutter app, installed Pixel 4a virtual device, but when I tried to start an app, I get the error shown below on Macbook M1.

**ERROR OPENING EMULATOR **

> INFO | Android emulator version 32.1.14.0 (build_id 10330179) (CL:N/A) INFO | Found systemPath /Users/seymencanaydogan/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-34/google_apis/arm64-v8a/ ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD ERROR | is an experimental feature. ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature. INFO | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-seymencanaydogan/emu-crash.db, detection is enabled INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.

I have the latest Android studio, Android virtual device, Flutter and Dart plugins. Also in Flutter doctor, everything is normal no issues found.

> Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.5, on macOS 13.4.1 22F82 darwin-arm64, locale     en-TR) [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0) [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1) [✓] Chrome - develop for the web [✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2) [✓] Connected device (3 available) [✓] Network resources

Should I add Android SDK to my path or something. I have no idea right now. Help me please!

Comment: Does this [stackoverflow-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328499/emulator-emulator-error-running-multiple-emulators-with-the-same-avd-is-an-ex)  answer your question?