# Emulator Error: Running multiple emulators with the same AVD ERROR

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

Facing this error:

```
Error Opening Emulator
INFO | Android emulator version 32.1.12.0 (build_id 9751036) (CL:N/A)
INFO | Found systemPath C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-28\google_apis\x86\
ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD
ERROR | is an experimental feature.
ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature.
INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash.db, detection is enabled
INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
INFO | IPv4 server found: 192.168.101.1
```

I tried following all the youtube videos and solutions provided on multiple platforms but it did not work for me.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXybP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Removing the .lock files did the trick for me. Find the avd and remove the lock files. In a Mac `.android/avd/'NAMEOFAVD.avd directory` . The files I removed were  `hardware-qemu.ini.lock` and  `multiinstance.lock`

You can find other solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328499/emulator-emulator-error-running-multiple-emulators-with-the-same-avd-is-an-ex#:%7E:text=Same%20emulator%20error-,ERROR%3A%20Running%20multiple%20emulators%20with%20the,AVD%20is%20an%20experimental%20feature.&text=The%20very%20simple%20solution%20which,It%20works%20all%20the%20time.),